# Python Imaging Library will not install (from source, python setup.py install) with Mac OS X Panther with Xcode

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I have a 700MHz iMac G4 (which is PowerPC and has 256MB of RAM) running Apple Mac OS X Panther 10.3.9, and I've installed Python 2.7 and ActiveTcl (which I don't think is relevant, the ActiveTcl) and I'm trying to install the Python Imaging Library from source. I've unarchived it, cd-ed into the directory and run the command "python setup.py install". (Without quotes)
I get an error message stating that it cannot find an appropriate compiler, which is really strange as I have Xcode 1.5 on the machine, and GCC is in the PATH.
I don't have internet access on the machine, so I copy files from a laptop with WiFi via a USB stick. (#irrelevantDetails it's USB 1.1 and horribly slow)
Can you give me some intel on how to get the thing to install please? ;)
Thanks a bunch.

Comment: use pillow instead of pil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the commenter said above

PIL is generally not recommended anymore

Pillow is the modern solution and it is on PyPi!

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.4.0